# Cannot add/remove class with jQuery in IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery to show and hide sections in a page. The approach works in Chrome, FF, and Safari, but it breaks in IE8 and 7.  Tried using animate, fade, and opacity. Nothing seems to work in IE.  According to the IE Developer Tools' js console, the selected elements have a class of 'active', but when I look at the dom tree in the Dev Tools html window, the 
active' class has not been removed or rewritten to the DOM.

The Mark-up

```
<nav> 
<ul>
<li id="foo">Show Section 1</li>
<li id="bar">Show Section 2</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="items">
<section class="foo">Content Section 1</section>
<section class="bar">Content Section 2</section>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#items > section {display: none;}
.active {display: block;}
```

The JS

```
$('nav li').click(function(){
    var $me = $(this);
showSection($me.attr('id'));
});

showSection function(whichSection){
    $('#items > section').removeClass('active');    
    $('#items > '+'.'+whichSection).addClass('active');
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I am under a nasty deadline. Cheers.

Comment: You might need to include html5shiv (or Modernizr) to get IE8 to recognize the HTML5 tags.

Comment: Does your HTML validate?  Also, see Adam's comment.

Comment: I don't see how your example works anywhere.

Comment: There are some errors in the Firefox web console. Some of them are expected, but some aren't. I better dig into these. We are using Modernizr.

Comment: I tried to re-write the script for readability. The actual script is much longer and has some project specific naming in it. Pardon me if I broke the script in that process. The actual script does work in most browser.

Answer (score 2):

You have your id's and classes mixed up.

```
$('nav li').click(function(){
    var $me = $(this);
    showSection($me.attr('id'));
});

showSection function(whichSection){
    $('#items > section').removeClass('active');    
    $('#items > #' + whichSection).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick I just caught that. I should have made a fiddle for this example code. I was rushing to try and get some feedback. Thanks for the help. The original question remains though, so if you have ideas about what else could be happening, specifically in IE, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you function declaration was wrong:

```
  function showSection (whichSection){
      $('#items > section').removeClass('active');    
      $('#items > #' + whichSection).addClass('active');
  }
```

Or

```
   var showSection = function(whichSection){
        $('#items > section').removeClass('active');    
        $('#items > #' + whichSection).addClass('active');
    }
```

**NOTE: IE don't understand the** `section`. **So you can use** ***html5shiv / Modernizr.*** to find out HTML5 tags.

Comment: Thank you. I did a really poor job of writing the example code. In the real version the function is an object method.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and below do not understand `section` tag unless you force it know the tag, you can use `html5shiv` js library.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv